# jquery Toggle a popup and then auto hide the popup

Tags: jquery, popup

I'd like to simply toggle a popup when I mouse click and then auto hide that popup after a few seconds.

Here's what I have so far. (this is borrowed from w3schools). right now the pop-up will display when I click, but doesn't go away unless I click the element again. How can it just auto hide?

```
</head>
<body style="text-align:center">

<h2>Popup</h2>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>

<script>
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
    //
    // execute the timeout function after 1 second
    //
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("myPopup").classList.toggle("show");
    }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.show {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<h2>Popup</h2>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>
```

Using only CSS [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s 1s, opacity 1s linear;
}
.show {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<h2>Popup</h2>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! amazing resposne time :) one more question...is there a way to have it timeout and fade out rather than just hide instantly?